# Speech Recognition Packages for ROS Kinetic Kame

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, folks !

I need a speech recognition package for Kinetic Kame. I have looked at some packages like pocketsphinx but they are not for Kinetic Kame. Do you have any advice about how speech recognition works on Kinetic Kame ?

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246247/speech-recognition-packages-for-ros-kinetic-kame/) by [canoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28321/canoski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-02-08**:
I would be interested in this as well...any more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I see it, you have 2 alternatives. There's a Python version:
https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/pocketsphinx

And a gstreamer version:
https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx/pull/16

The Python version is supposedly faster and definitely easier to define new commands for. It uses an out-of-the-box CMUdict dictionary. Unfortunately, afaik, it can't be re-trained to match your specific needs.

The gstreamer version is a bit harder to use but it allows re-training, for example, if you have a strong accent.

There's also Google speech-to-text, which costs $ but its performance is amazing and it recognizes >100 languages/dialects.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-27**:
Tried the version from mikeferguson, works for me.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-04-27**:
That's good. I prefer my Python fork because it's easy to define your list of keywords and supposedly faster. Very good accuracy now that my sampling rate is correct, too. Should be a drop-in replacement for the original package.

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2017-08-08**:
Hello

I use Ros kinetix and ubuntu 16.0 but this link does not work for me.
on the shell I just see some data but I can not recognize the words

I tried this link but does not work for me .
https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/pocketsphinx

(INFO:n_live.c(105): Update to   < 50.78  0.51  0

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-08-08**:
If you're seeing lines of output when you speak, it means Pocketsphinx is running but it may not recognize your speech. Do you have a strong accent? You can download different language models (e.g. Indian) here. [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/)

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2017-08-08**:
thanks but I think it is not because of accent, because we have tried it with different accents.
You re also right Pocketsphinx is running , but as I mentioned, I just see this interesting lines

INFO:n_live.c(105): Update form .....
INFO:n_live.c(105): Update to ....

Do I miss sthg. else ?